# Transform Dictionary<string, int> to Dictionary<int, List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

**Q** How can I most efficiently convert a `Dictionary<string, int>` `to a Dictionary<int, List<string>>`?

**Example**

```
var input = new Dictionary<string, int>() { {"A", 1}, {"B", 1}, {"C", 2} ...
Dictionary<int, List<string>> result = Transform(input)
Assert.IsTrue(result, { {1, {"A", "B"}}, {2, {"C"}} ... });
```

Comment: what did you try? is that a homework? interview?

Comment: Data structure you going to use is: ILookup. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var result = 
    dict.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key)
    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

Although I don't see why you couldn't just use the result from `dict.ToLookup()` without changing it to a dictionary, for example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"One", 1},
    {"Two", 2},
    {"1", 1},
    {"TWO", 2},
    {"ii", 2}
};

var test = dict.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", test[2])); // Prints: Two, TWO, ii
```

Answer (score 5):

Group the dictionary by values and map the group keys to list of keys:

```
input.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(_ => _.Key).ToList())
```

Comment: That's not exactly what the OP requested. The value of each item in the dictionary would be a `List` of `KeyValuePair` instead of just list of "A", "B" etc. Perhaps you want `input.GroupBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(z => z.Key).ToList());`

Comment: @haim770 you are right, need to add a Select, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to achieve.

```
    private static Dictionary<int, List<string>> Transform(Dictionary<string, int> input)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
        foreach (var value in input.Select(x => x.Value).Distinct())
        {
            var lst = input.Where(x => x.Value == value).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
            result.Add(value, lst);
        }
        return result;
    }
```